# How to remove some options of Intent Chooser

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating a chooser,I wang to add a option that i want to,so I must delete the exised options.The following is my code:

```
private Intent createChooser(Intent targetintent){
    Intent chooser=Intent.createChooser(targetintent, getString(R.string.choose_an_app));
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> infoList  =pm.queryIntentActivities(targetintent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    Log.i("TAG","size  "+infoList.size());
    List<LabeledIntent> labeledIntents = new ArrayList<>();
        for(ResolveInfo ri:infoList){
        String packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
        if(packageName.contains("android.providers.media")){//系统的 media stroage

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, ri.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setAction(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
            labeledIntents.add(new LabeledIntent(intent, packageName, ri.loadLabel(pm), ri.icon));
        }
    }
    LabeledIntent[] extraIntents = labeledIntents.toArray( new LabeledIntent[ labeledIntents.size() ]);
    Log.i("TAG","extarsize "+labeledIntents.size());

    chooser.removeExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS);
    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,extraIntents);

    return chooser;
```

}

I use this code

```
chooser.removeExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS);
chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,extraIntents);
```

to remove the existed options and then add my options,but not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing specific items/options from the intent chooser is not possible. So create your own custom list view/dialog similar to the default chooser dialog with your targeted options.

You already have your targeted package name and you can get and set the app icon through `iconImageView.setImageDrawable(info.loadIcon(getPackageManager()));`

Comment: I have used this `Intent chooser=Intent.createChooser(targetintent, getString(R.string.choose_an_app));`, so there are some existd options that from the targetIntet before I add my custom options,

Comment: so I must remove this code,you are right,we can not remove the options,thank you!

Comment: If there is only one item/option,the chooser also shows on android 6.0 but not on less than android 6.0  @Amit K. Saha

Comment: does it matter when you are going to make your own custom chooser dialog?